# How to get control in ASP.NET PreInit event?

Tags: asp.net, null, controls, preinit

How to get control in ASP.NET PreInit event? Pointers are null and FindControl method returns null.

I am using master and content pages.
Markup of the content page looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" runat="server">
   <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="100%">
      .....
   </asp:Table>
</asp:Content>
```

And code like this:

```
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control table = this.FindControl("Table1");
    //table is null here
}
```

So table still is null after this.FindControl("Table1"). NamingContainer of the page is null too. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** I have to use this event to create controls. As said in the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) this event should be used for dynamic control creation. I need to create a list of links in my table. May be there is another way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong.  Do you have to use the PreInit event?  Can you use a later event like Init?

Comment: Like Matthew says a later event might suit you better. I suspect that its in init that a lot of the controls actually get put together so if you try to access things too early in the lifecycle it all falls apart. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx might be useful if you havent' already seen it.

Comment: Having read your edit I generally add stuff to the control tree in the page_load event. Not sure what that section you quoted is referring to to be honest but I don't think it means just adding a link to a page...

Answer (score 5):

PreInit is fired before the controls are initialized.  Read up on the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more detailed information.

> **Init** 
>   Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin
>   settings have been applied. The Init
>   event of individual controls occurs
>   before the Init event of the page.
>
> **Use this event to read or initialize
>   control properties.**

Answer (score 1):

In the PreInit() event, standard (defined) controls have not been created yet at that stage, thus you cannot get any reference to any controls.

Use the Page_Load() event to create dynamic controls. During this event, you can add any dynamic controls into existing controls.

After creating the dynamic controls in Page_Load(), use the PreRender() to make any changes/updates.

Personally, I use PreInit to define page wide objects (ie, database connections, user session objects) and also where I perform security authentication checks (and redirects if not authorized) only.

Answer (score 1):

The Page's PreInit event is triggered before the controls are initialized, so controls do not exist yet. You will have to access the control in a later event, such as the Page's Load event. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between Pages with or without a Master Page as explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761273/difference-with-creating-and-adding-controls-in-preinit-init) in the Question and Answers.

Without a Master Page you can create controls in the PreInit event and add them to an existing control but with a Master Page you cannot access the existing controls yet, as explained in the answers here, so you have to create dynamic controls in a later event like the Init event.

Since you are using a Master Page you should create your dynamic controls in a later event like the Init event or try the option given there by Valio.